# хранение списка в текстовом документе

Tags: python, массивы, файлы, списки

приведите пример кода с хранением списка в txt файле

Comment: http://www.clinuxworld.com/admin/426-simple-serialization

Answer (score 1):

Сериализация в JSON приводит к преобразованию списка Python в текст, который и будет сохранён, собственно говоря, в текстовом файле.

```
import json
test_l = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(test_l, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pickle


data = [1, 2, 3]

with open('data.txt', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data_new = pickle.load(f)
```

В этом примере с помощью модуля pickle было произведено сохранение списка в текстовый файл, а потом загрузка из этого текстового файла.

Модуль pickle позволяет сериализировать для сохранения в файл или передачи по сети не только списки, но и многие другие объекты. Стандартные питоновские структуры данных поддерживаются все, емнип.

Для более подробной информации гуглите модуль pickle.

Совет на будущее: постарайтесь так не формулировать вопросы. Хороший вопрос включает в себя внятное описание того, какой результат вы хотите получить в итоге, и в чём именно состоит проблема, которая не позволяет вам получить этот результат самостоятельно.